# PHP not closing TCP CLOSE_WAIT on web server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

My web server has a lot of apache tcp `CLOSE_WAIT`'s stuck at `poll(found through a backtrace in gdb)`, How do I debug what in php is causing my web server to not properly close connections?

Comment: This just means your PHP code is opening connections but not closing them. It's not an Apache problem. Try to track down which PHP script it is.

Answer (score 0):

Install/enable mod_status, configure it to allow access from your URL and access the server with `<server-ip>/server-status`

You should see a list of all current active client connections including vhost and path.

IIRC had this problem when a badly configured crawler hit a website that used a not properly implemented php script that handled images. It tried to access all those images as if it were links causing huge load and many open connections.